# @OneToMany and @ManyToOne Spring Data JPA Child does not update Parent

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

I am struggling with simple scenario, where I have to specify a Team of Many developers and a Developer can only have one team.

These are my current two POJOs, but it is starting to get complex and i start to hate it. Not sure what is the best approach.

```java
@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"team"})
@ToString(exclude = {"team"})
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Developer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"developers"})
    private Team team;

}
```

```java
@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"developers"})
@ToString(exclude = {"developers"})
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Team {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    private String description;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "team", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"team"})
    private List<Developer> developers;

}
```

The problem I have now is if I create a Team and then assign two developers to it and then retrieve the team again, the developers list is still null. What am i missing? I can manually update the list of the team of course, but that defeats the purpose of JPA helping me. Any advice would be helpful.

```java
    @Autowired
    private TeamRepository underTest;

    @Autowired
    private DeveloperRepository developerRepository;

Team team = Team.builder()
        .name("Team 1")
        .build();

Team team1 = underTest.save(team);

Developer developer1 = Developer.builder()
        .name("Stefan Bratanov")
        .team(team1)
        .build();

Developer developer2 = Developer.builder()
        .name("Darth Vader")
        .team(team1)
        .build();

List<Developer> developers = Arrays.asList(developer1, developer2);

developerRepository.saveAll(developers);

Optional<Team> maybeTeamWithDevelopers = underTest.findById(team1.getId());
assertThat(maybeTeamWithDevelopers).isPresent();

Team teamWithDevelopers = maybeTeamWithDevelopers.get();

assertThat(teamWithDevelopers.getDevelopers()).containsExactlyInAnyOrder(developer1, developer2); //DEVELOPERS IS NULL HERE
```

Comment: using lombok on entities is for my concern a bad practice

Comment: JPA isn't helping you, it is a tool for serializing the data to a database - it is still up to you to manage your java objects. The specification even spells out that you are responsible to maintain both sides of any bidirectional relationships to ensure they are in synch with what you are pushing into the database. You don't have to, but if you don't, you will run into seemingly odd situations like this where it seems to work when you re-load or the app starts up, but not at others. And it will prevent use of caching as a performance option later on.

Comment: Thank you, i agree the JPA entities are only one layer and the code logic shouldn't be dependent entirely on its intricacies

Answer (score 1):

```java
    @Entity
    @Data
    @EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"developers"})
    @ToString(exclude = {"developers"})
    @Builder
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class Team {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Long id;
    
        @Column(nullable = false)
        private String name;
    
        private String description;
    
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "team", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"team"})
        private List<Developer> developers = new ArrayList<>;
        
        Team addDeveloper(Developer dev) {
            dev.setTeam(this);
            this.getDevelopers().add(dev);
            return this;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but if a team is created, and afterwards a developer is created with this team, shouldn't team.getDevelopers() just resolve automatically

Comment: Since you have the persist cascade, create your teams, add their developers (with the adder function I wrote) and only save the teams. Everything should work fine. You can assert that developers have an id

Comment: @StefanBr93 no it should not work, if you have a bidirectional relationship you need to set both sides of the relationship, otherwise you have conflicting states of the related entities. Be mindful that absence of something has a meaning as well, otherwise it would be hard to remove a relationship between 2 entities

Comment: You are right, i figured it out actually. The @DataJpaTest tests by default work as part of a transaction, so the team entity was not getting updated. I used @Transactional(propagation = NOT_SUPPORTED) on top of the test which fixed it